# no visible binding for global variable ‘.’

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I'm currently co-developing an `R` package using `devtools`. We use the
tidyverse `%>%` and associated `purrr` and `dplyr` packages within our
functions.

One of our functions is as follows (edited for clarity):

```r
#' Print `cust_modl` object
#'
#' @param x A `cust_modl` object.
#' @param ... Additional arguments passed to `print.cust_modl()` to print the
#'   object.
#'
#' @method print cust_modl
#' @export
print.cust_modl <- function(x, ...) {

req_var_nms <- x$var %>%
purrr::compact(.x = .) %>%
names(x = .)

comp_var_ind_filt <- req_var_nms %>%
purrr::map(.x = ., .f = ~ purrr::pluck(x$var, .x))

}
```

This is currently giving an `NOTE` in our Github Actions `devtools::check()` as:

```
print.cust_modl: no visible binding for global variable ‘.’
```

I understand that this error is due to `rlang` related issues based on [this helpful post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-solve-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-note/28887/3?u=shamindras). So typically we use `@importFrom rlang .data` as suggested and ensure
that in `dplyr` we carry the `.data$` syntax correctly when referencing columns.

However, it seems that this `NOTE` was being given by the `purrr` calls and it is not
clear how to correct the `rlang` import for just the `.` (rather than the usual more explicit
`.data` call in `dplyr`).

Could anyone please explain how to correctly adjust R package code for the `.` as called by
tidyverse packages such as `purrr`? I understand that we can locally set `. <- NULL`, but is there a more rigorous way to set this using `rlang`? Understanding the recommended guidelines here would allow our package to be developed to community standards.

**Disclaimer:** This is now cross-posted from [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable/99969), since it hasn't received a reply in several days.

Comment: This page might be helpful: https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/451#issuecomment-264598618

Comment: Many thanks @WillOldham. I'd seen this link. If you scroll down, this comment: https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/451#issuecomment-385731301, suggests the fix for `dplyr` verbs using `rlang`. In the case I'm asking for it is to control the `.` specifically i.e. outside of `dplyr`. Would you have any ideas how to fix for this case? The GlobalVariables approach can have other implications, which I'm trying to safely avoid.

Comment: Use `utils::globalVariables(".")` to silence this.

Comment: Many thanks @LionelHenry (for this and your contributions to tidyeval). Just for further clarification, I have a few follow up questions. 1. Could this `utils::globalVariables(".")` approach have unintended global side-effects? 2. Is the only advantage of using `utils::globalVariables(".")` over `. <- NULL` locally is that it needs to be set once, or are there more issues with the `NULL` local approach. 3. I'm curious whether there are any `dplyr` `.data` style fixes for this specific issue, since the `.` is commonly passed around in `%>%` code?

Comment: For unintended effects, the flip side of declaring a global variable is that you won't get warnings when you use `.` in a place where it is not defined. In that case though, it is unlikely you would call a real variable `.` so there is no issue. Regarding `. <- NULL`, the `globalVariables()` declariation is more explicit. I'm not aware of an importable `.` but this were possible there would be no advantage to importing it over declaring it global.

Comment: Thanks @LionelHenry. This is really helpful. One last question. Should we then add it like this in our main package level doc: https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/blob/master/R/googlesheets.R#L15-L16? Is there any advantage to add the `if(getRversion() >= "2.15.1")` line?

Comment: The conditional makes it work on R < 2.15.1. This is a really old version.

Comment: I got a little confused by this. Doesn't the `globalVariables(".")` only get executed if the `R >= "2.15.1"`. Since there is no else expression, I thought this means that there is no such `globalVariables(".")` assignment for `R < 2.15.1` i.e. older versions of `R` are **not** covered by this global variable. I don't expect any of our package users to have such an old `R` version, but it seems to me like this constraint does not cover the older version. Sorry for being naive here, but could you clarify the issue in my thinking above?

Comment: @user4687531, if not the OP, tag the person for them to receive a notification. The if(getRversion() >= "2.15.1") prevents build failure on R versions <2.15.1, where globalVariables doesn't exist. Attempting to call it would result in an error. Not declaring . in these versions merely gives a minor warning during RCHECK, not during build/load - it's a negligible issue (probably either way).

Answer (score 6):

This alert comes from the `codetools` package. Apart from the other solution, there is also an option of not using `codetools` completely in R CMD check. In your `~/.Renviron` file (to quickly open from R console, use `usethis::edit_r_environ()`), add a line as such:

```
_R_CHECK_USE_CODETOOLS_= FALSE
```

This is recommended if you do a lot of NSE which throws many false alerts.

Comment: Turning this off would prevent valid warnings of undeclared variables though correct? As in, you wouldn't get a warning that you reference a global variable